# Binning a Phase Folded Lightcurve

Tags: astrophysics, light-curve

How do I bin a messy phase folded lightcurve? This is one of the phase folded generated plots for a variable star. I plotted the phase using the period extracted by Lomb-Scargle Periodogram algorithm. I need to bin them say by ~100 or so. Kindly help me out. [image: Phase Folded Light Curve]

This is the periodigram obtained using Lomb-Scargle method.
[image: Lomb-Scargle Periodogram]

Comment: I would have expected a much smoother curve. IMO, either it has not been folded properly or the curve is dominated by statistical errors (i.e. no detection)

Comment: Another reason could it be noise destruction.

Comment: I plotted the periodogram and got the frequency as I expected. When I plotted the phase folded curve, I got this.

Comment: If you'd like, you can post more information, like a few lines of the code you used to obtain it, the plot of the peridogram and a plot of the original data (possibly dot-plots, not line-plots, for visual clarity). I'm not an expert, but I'd be happy to help you pinpoint the problem

Comment: Yes, I've edited the question. I have added the periodogram.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**: try a finer frequency grid to obtain the correct period, bin it with the function `astropy.timeseries.aggregate_downsample`

Before addressing the binning, you have to obtain a correct phase folded plot. You rightly call it "messy", the most likely reason is that the period you chose is wrong (assuming the data actually contains a periodic signal with good S/N).

I understand you might not want to share your code. I will then make some assumptions:

- you are using `python`, `matplotlib` and `astropy`
- you have computed the peridogram using `astropy.timeseries.LombScargle`
- you have used the default `normalization='standard'`
- you have taken the frequency of the highest peak on the plot you posted and used it to phase-fold the data

In general, blindly taking the highest peak of the peridogram that comes out of the Lomb-Scargle is often not the best approach. In particular in this case the highest peak has a value of about $\approx 0.020$, which is definitely low. The correct period usually comes with peridogram values higher than $0.4$ (the maximum is $1$). But don't take this as a rule. You may use the method `false_alarm_probability` to better quantify the probability that the peak is significant and not random.

I believe that you have not found the correct period because you have used a too coarse frequency grid. The period lies between the points and you have missed it. Use a **much** finer frequency grid and you might be able to see a new peak appearing, very high and narrow. Alternatively, if you don't want to choose the spacing yourself, you may use the `autopower` method, that should find the best frequency grid for you.

After you have found the correct period and your folded curve makes sense, binning is the easiest part, there is a function that does just that: `astropy.timeseries.aggregate_downsample`.

Everything that I just said (and much more) is explained in the documentation of `astropy`, which is really complete and easy to understand. I cannot stress it enough, **read the documentation** and you will find that most of the problems you may encounter are already addressed there:

[astropy: Lomb-Scargle](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/timeseries/lombscargle.html)

[astropy: Time Series](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/timeseries/index.html)

And a more technical paper that explains the capabilities and limitations of the Lomb-Scargle, I suggest you keep it as a reference:

[Understanding the Lomb-Scargle Periodogram](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2018ApJS..236...16V)

Comment: The Vanderplas paper is excellent.

Comment: @ProfRob I just discovered it this morning, I am really impressed

Comment: There are some interesting things here: http://vanderplas.com/ Though not about Astronomy *per se* I linked to their github in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34572718/3904031). Also, there are some other [Lomb-Scargle questions](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=Scargle) and [periodogram questions](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=Periodogram) that may also be in need of additional attention.